# Converting binary to list

Tags: r, list, dplyr, binary

I have somating like a binary dataframe

```
> dput(head(dat))
structure(list(CDR3.aa = c("CALWEVQELGKKIKVF", "CAATVGGWGKLQF", 
"CACDPLYGGITGGFNTDKLIF", "CACDTLLPTSLGDMAKLIF", "CALGELSSDGGGAIF", 
"CALSNTGGFKTIF"), TCR_CS001_T1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), TCR_CS001_T2 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0), TCR_CS002 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TCR_HC002 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1), TCR_HC003 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000023f7a101ef0>, class = c("immunr_public_repertoire", 
"data.table", "data.frame"))
```

That shows if an amin acide exists in a sample we see 1 and if absent shown by 0

I want to replace 1 and 0 by amino acid itself

How I can do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CDR3.aa` is the amino acid column you can do :

`dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(across(-CDR3.aa, ~ifelse(. == 1,  CDR3.aa, .)))

#                 CDR3.aa          TCR_CS001_T1          TCR_CS001_T2        TCR_CS002
#1:      CALWEVQELGKKIKVF      CALWEVQELGKKIKVF                     0 CALWEVQELGKKIKVF
#2:         CAATVGGWGKLQF         CAATVGGWGKLQF         CAATVGGWGKLQF                0
#3: CACDPLYGGITGGFNTDKLIF CACDPLYGGITGGFNTDKLIF CACDPLYGGITGGFNTDKLIF                0
#4:   CACDTLLPTSLGDMAKLIF   CACDTLLPTSLGDMAKLIF   CACDTLLPTSLGDMAKLIF                0
#5:       CALGELSSDGGGAIF       CALGELSSDGGGAIF       CALGELSSDGGGAIF                0
#6:         CALSNTGGFKTIF                     0                     0                0

#       TCR_HC002        TCR_HC003
#1:             0 CALWEVQELGKKIKVF
#2:             0                0
#3:             0                0
#4:             0                0
#5:             0                0
#6: CALSNTGGFKTIF    CALSNTGGFKTIF
```

`data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
dat[, (names(dat)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == 1,  CDR3.aa, x)), .SDcols = -1]
```

Comment: Yes CDR3.aa is amino acid column. This returns a list how I get a data frame instead please?

Comment: Did you want the amino acid as a character (as described above by Roman) or a factor ?  Factors effectively make the dataset smaller ... Sometimes they are helpful sometimes they aren't. Often other functions will convert characters to factors.

Comment: I am getting some zeros again instead I want empty cells instead of zeros like the picture I posted now

Comment: If you want empty cells you can do `dat %>% mutate(across(-CDR3.aa, ~ifelse(. == 1,  CDR3.aa, '')))`